# UK and France visa

Tags: visas, uk, france, indian-citizens

I am planning to go to the UK with my brother. I've been to the UK two times last year, but my brother is a freshy and this will be his first foreign trip. We want to travel to Paris during our visit to the UK. What advice is there to minimize the chances of problems in obtaining these visas. We are holding Indian passports and our financial condition is strong.

Comment: Provide all the documents and proofs required by the UK and the Schengen country you are visiting.

Answer (score 5):

You have asked how to apply for a visa for two different sovereignties.  Accordingly, you will need to file two applications...

### For the UK...

[image]

1. Read the guidance at [Guide to Supporting Documents](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/343241/2014_08_Visitor_Documents.pdf)
2. Assemble all of the requisite documents, including photographs
3. Determine if you will need one of the priority services
4. Create an account at [Visa4UK](https://www.visa4uk.fco.gov.uk/) and be sure your printer has lots of ink
5. Fill out the on-line application
6. In the final step, select the appropriate centre for your biometric
   enrolment and make an appointment
7. Follow the instructions on the last page of the on-line application

Once all of those have been completed, gather up all of your stuff and take it to the Visa Application Centre designed for your particular region (this will be identified for you when you make an appointment).

---

---

### For Schengen...

[image]
The [application process for France](http://www.vfs-france.co.in/) is largely the same but you cannot use the same biometrics sample. Read the [guidance](http://www.vfs-france.co.in/pdf/Schengen_Common_Information_Sheet.pdf) first.  In this case you must download the form at [Application Forms](http://www.vfs-france.co.in/PDF/Visa_Form_France_Schengen_Revised_040214.pdf).  Note that they are piloting a new SMS service which you may find useful.

NOTE:  You are intending to visit these countries as part of the same voyage and this is material information to both applications.  I recommend doing the Schengen first and enclosing the application reference number with the UK application.